# Can we create an array dynamically in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have a user input in my app, according to which, the number of arrays that I need to create changes (user inputs the number of channels into which I need to split an incoming data stream, with one array for each channel). The number of channels can be any multiple of 4 up to 32. I want to know whether there is a way to automatically initialize arrays, perhaps using *for* loops like in this pseudocode:

```
for(initialization, numberOfChannels, increment) {
    NSString (set array name to channel%dArray, i);
    NSMutableArray *channeliArray = [[NSAMutablerray alloc] init];
}
```

Everywhere I've looked, I didn't find any way to set the name of the array dynamically and hence allow initializations like the one above. Even using a 2D array would have the same problem. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Uh, this is what arrays are for.

Comment: Why do you believe a two dimensional array would not solve this problem?

Comment: By the way, the above "initialization" would not initialize anything, even if you could get it to work.  You've made `channeliArray` a variable declared inside the loop, so its value basically goes "poof" as soon as you leave the loop.

Comment: @Jonah because I would create a 2D array like this:
Step1 - NSMutableArray *channel1Array = [[NSAMutablerray alloc] init];
Step2 - [mainArray addObject:channel1Array];

Now if I have 32 arrays I would have to do both steps 32 times! Instead if I could use a *for* loop to automate Step1 for me, things would be much simpler.

Comment: @HotLicks Oh right! But anyway, I just wrote that to give an idea of what I want. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Do it the same way you'd do it in C or Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a two dimensional array as per @Jonah's comments -

```
self.channels=[NSMutableArray new];

for (int i=0;i<numberOfChannels;i++) {
   [self.channels addObject:[NSMutableArray new]];
}
```

Then you can access a particular channel's array by index -

```
NSMutableArray *channel=[self.channels objectAtIndex:channelNumber];
```

Or, if you wanted to use channel names as per your pseudocode, use a dictionary of arrays

```
self.channels=[NSMutableDictionary new];

for (int i=0;i<numberOfChannels;i++) {
      [self.channels setObject:[NSMutableArray new] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"channel%dArray",i]];
}
```

Then you can access a particular channel's array by name -

```
NSMutableArray *channelArray=[self.channels objectForKey:@"channel3Array"];
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you use `objectAtIndex:` and `objectForKey:` instead of subscripting?

Comment: Habit.  I have been coding ObjC since before the shorthand methods were available, so if I don't think about it my hands will type the access methods without thinking about it :)

Comment: I am that long in the business too. But especially when dealing with newbies I use subscripting as much as possible, as it is syntactically known from other languages.